# Is it possible to round a number to nearest .5 with Smarty PHP?

Tags: php, smarty

So, I'd like to do the following:

1.1, 1.2 rounded down to 1.0,

1.3, 1.4 rounded up to 1.5,

1.6, 1.7 rounded down to 1.5,

1.8, 1.9 rounded up to 2.0 etc.

The reason for this is to use a sprite to display whole or half stars as a product rating. Currently I am using the below code to display the non-rounded values.

```
$product.product_rating | number_format : '1' | replace : '.' : '-';
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Even if there _isn't,_ you can always multiply by two, round to the nearest integer and then divide by two.

Comment: Did you read about http://php.net/number_format ?

Comment: Or add 0.5 and then round to the nearest integer.

Comment: You can write your own smarty modifier for it. Look [here](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.modifiers.tpl)